# Proving equivalence relation on matrices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R = M_2(\mathbb{R})$ the set of all square $2$x$2$ matrices with real coefficients.

$A,B \in R$, define $A$ ~ $B$, if and only if, exist $P \in R$ inversible such that $A=P^{-1}BP$.

Prove that ~ is a equivalence relation.

What I'm trying:

Proving the equivalence relation:

Reflexive: $A$~$A$, so we can write $P=I$, and get $A=A$

Symmetric: $A$~$B$, so $A=P^{-1}BP$, that implies $B=PAP^{-1}$, and here, we can just switch the notation and write $B=P^{-1}AP$. (I'm not sure about that at all)

Transitive: $A$~$B$ and $B$~$C$, so there's $P$, and $T$, such that, $A=P^{-1}BP$ and $B=T^{-1}CT$

Substituing $B$ into the first equation: $A=P^{-1}T^{-1}CTP$. Which helps nothing, because $P^{-1}T^{-1}$ isn't the inverse of $TP$. (This one I actually have no ideia how to show that.)

If there's something wrong in the first two please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think everything looks right, and I'm not sure why you say $P^{-1}T^{-1}$ isn't the inverse of $TP$, because it is. In general, for invertible matrices $A$ and $B$, $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh gosh, silly me. You're right. I forgot that totally... Thanks.